# how to show or hide list in while typing in text field?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, ionic-framework

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZGEpMN

hello 
I am trying to make auto complete in ionic using angularjs.I am able to make auto complete but I found some issue .I need to display my filter list when user type on input field .In other words Currently my list is display every time.I need to display my list when I type anything on text field .And when I remove all text from text field it should again hide .could you please tell me how I will achieve this thing

here is my code

```
 <div class="listcontainer">
        <li class="item" ng-repeat="station in data.data | filter:station.stationCode:startsWith">{{station.stationName+"-("+station.stationCode+")"}}</li>
    </div>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZGEpMN

**secondly** :
why my list is not scrolling ? when i touch up and touchdown it is not scrolling /?

```
.listcontainer{
  border :1px solid blue;
  height:150px;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: one question per question.

Comment: For your scroll problem.... try `overflowY: scroll`

Comment: not working..please check codepen

Comment: scrolling works on codepen with `overflow: auto`.... but you have to type something in the textfield.... if not, there are no items...

Comment: @marcel  not working http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZGEpMN

Comment: this works.... http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wavoGQ

Answer (score 0):

Just change

```
<div class="listcontainer">
```

to

```
<div class="listcontainer" ng-show="station.stationCode.length">
```

This will result in angular hiding your complete div.listcontainer when length of your above defined model is false (zero).

Comment: just `station.stationCode` would work. Empty string is falsey too

Comment: @SergioTulentsev could you please give more information

Comment: Try without the `.length`. Worked for me

Comment: yes than it working ..but why the list is not scrolling

Comment: @SergioTulentsev do you have any idea why it is not scrolling my list

Comment: @user944513: nope, no idea. And stick to one question per question in the future, please.

Answer (score 0):

Use a html select element with ng-options to show your suggestions. When you jhavent typed anything the list of suggestions is empty, and selectbox closed.
As soon as you start typing and suggestions arrive from backend then the selectbox will open and show your suggestions. Something like this:

```
<select ng-options="station in data.data | filter:station.stationCode:startsWith">
```

Note: when using

items surround them with  or